# How to call this DLL function from either C++ / C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke

I'm taking a lot of time trying to figure this out, so I thought I could get some help here.
Basically I have a DLL function declared like this in IDL:

```
[id(1), helpstring("method findFile")] HRESULT findFile(
    [in] BSTR fileName,
    [out] LONG* someValue
    );
```

How exactly do I declare and invoke from either C++ / C#?

Note: there is a VB6 app that successfully invokes the function. Declaration is:

```
 Private Declare Function findFile Lib "thedll.dll" ( _
    ByVal fileName As String, _
    ByRef someValueAs Long _
  )
```

The call:

```
Dim a As String
Dim b As Long
Dim r As long

a = "image.jpg"
b = -1
r = findFile(a, b)
```

**Addendum**:

I cannot guarantee that the VB6 code looks like that because I have the executable, I was only told what that portion looks like, so maybe you guys are right and it doesn't match. I did author the C++ DLL, and now I need to get together some code myself that successfully calls the DLL in order to try out stuff and not depend on that exe.

C++ implementation of the DLL function looks like this:

```
STDMETHODIMP CFinder::findFile(BSTR fileName, LONG* someValue)
{
    *someValue = 8;

    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: I'm being somewhat sceptical. If you `declare` this function (as opposed to using a TLB file), it'll fail because 1) `fileName` will be marshalled in the wrong way 2) Return value of `Variant` will unbalance stack (should be `Long`).

Comment: Please show the C++ source code that declares the function.

Answer (score 1):

Untested C# declaration:

```
[DllImport("thedll.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern int findFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]string fileName, out int someValue);
```

Comment: OK... at the function call I get this: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." I got to this point before, any clues?

Comment: This matches the IDL (apart from the `SetLastError` bit which is just wrong and should be removed). But the IDL and the VB6 don't match. Go figure!

Comment: I temporarily changed the DLL to not write output params, and the protected memory error disappeared. But I get this: "Program::findFile' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature."